# How can I solve this $(∀x)(∃y)P(x,y) <-> (∃y)(∀x)P(x,y)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Is the following example true?
If yes give explanation why ?
$$(∀x)(∃y)P(x,y) \leftrightarrow (∃y)(∀x)P(x,y)$$
I tried using values for $x$ and for $y$, and restricted them to the following: $x > 3$ and $y < 4$ but how can I be sure if this is true?
I have come across another question as well where for the function, $Q(x)$: $x$ is even $\to$ $x^2 - 4>0$ and the domain is $Z$. I tried to use the following: ${...-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,...}$ but I am not sure :D

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For every integer $x$, there exists an integer $y$ such that $x<y$.
2. There exists an integer $y$ such that, for all integers $x$, we have $x<y$.

The first is clearly true, and the second is nonsense. Therefore, the original claim that you're asking about is false.

---

Regarding your second question, it is not true that "$x$ is even" implies that $x^2-4>0$. Counterexamples are $x=-2, x=0$, and $x=2$. Whatever $Q(x)$ is supposed to be doing, it must have some way of excluding those values. I'm not sure why you'd be trying odd numbers, when they don't satisfy the condition in question.

Comment: ty what about the second question ?

Comment: I don't understand the second question

Comment: Well the second is we need to find the set of numbers that are true for the function

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll edit to add something about it.

Comment: @itmemilan I could not understand your second question either. It appears as if you’re asking which even numbers have a square greater than $4$, but that is a trivial question

Comment: Well my professor obviously doesn't want for the students to pass the class :D

Comment: oh and i got one more question if you can answer (sorry :D), from (A ∩ B' ∩ C') U (A ∩ B ∩ C) U (A' ∩ B ∩ C) is equal to ?

Comment: @itmemilan, have you drawn a Venn diagram of it?

Comment: The given answers are (B ⊕ C)' U ((A \ B) \ C) , (A-B-C) U (B ∩ C) , A ∩ (B' U C') U A and ((B U C)' ∩ A) U (A ∩ B ∩ C)

Comment: @GTonyJacobs you are talking about the second question ?

Comment: Draw a Venn for each, and see which one matches.

Comment: With Venn diagrams, I'm talking about this third question that you're asking in comments.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs oh okay, i figure out that one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131611/discussion-between-itmemilan-and-g-tony-jacobs).